# R reshaping / expanding dataset using survSplit to obtain time-varying variable for cox regression

Tags: r, reshape, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have seen other questions similar to this but they do not answer my question. I want to expand my dataset as I need to create a time-varying variable for survival analysis and want to use `survSplit` command (`survival` package) but my data is already partially in long format. Example data:

```
data1<-structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7), start = c(0, 183, 210, 241, 0, 183, 187, 212, 244, 0, 
118, 139, 188, 212, 237), no_days = c(NA, 28L, 28L, 28L, NA, 
7L, 28L, 28L, 28L, NA, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L), stop = c(NA, 
211, 238, 269, NA, 190, 215, 240, 272, NA, 146, 167, 216, 240, 
265), drug = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    dead = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), .Names = c("id", 
"start", "no_days", "stop", "drug", "dead"), row.names = c(NA, 
15L), class = "data.frame")

> head(data1,15)
   id start no_days stop drug dead
1   1     0      NA   NA    0    0
2   1   183      28  211    1    0
3   1   210      28  238    1    0
4   1   241      28  269    1    1
5   5     0      NA   NA    0    0
6   5   183       7  190    1    0
7   5   187      28  215    1    0
8   5   212      28  240    1    0
9   5   244      28  272    1    1
10  7     0      NA   NA    0    0
11  7   118      28  146    1    0
12  7   139      28  167    1    0
13  7   188      28  216    1    0
14  7   212      28  240    1    0
15  7   237      28  265    1    1
```

`Start` is the day the drug was prescribed, `no_days` is how long the prescription was for, `drug` indicates whether a person was on the drug for the given time period (this is the variable I need to make time-varying), `dead` indicates when a person died. At the moment the dataset only contains times an individual was on the drug so the final dataset I want should look like this:

```
 head(data1,18)
   id start no_days stop drug dead
1   1     0      NA  182    0    0
2   1   183      28  211    1    0
3   1   210      28  238    1    0
4   1   239      NA  240    0    0
5   1   241      28  269    1    1
6   5     0      NA  182    0    0
7   5   183       7  190    1    0
8   5   187      28  215    1    0
9   5   212      28  240    1    0
10  5   241      NA  243    0    0
11  5   244      28  272    1    1
12  7     0      NA  117    0    0
13  7   118      28  146    1    0
14  7   139      28  167    1    0
15  7   168      NA  187    0    0
16  7   188      28  216    1    0
17  7   212      28  240    1    0
18  7   237      28  265    1    1
```

Maybe this should be a standard data manipulation problem where I need to add more rows based on a certain criteria but considering it is survival data and `survSplit` was designed for this, albeit in a slightly different data structure to begin I was wondering is there an easy way to use `survSplit` to solve my problem. If not, does anyone have a simple suggestion to expand the dataframe.

My ultimate step is to fit a cox model something like:

```
coxph(Surv(data$start,data$stop,data$dead)~covariates + drug +cluster(id),data=data1)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following data wrangling with base R where essentially you `merge` dataframe with itself shifted by one row to align current and next record and then `transform` for *start* and *stop* calculations.

Note: `merge` will raise a warning (not error) of the duplicate `nextidcnt` column. Either ignore or create a second `data1` for the merge using `id` and `idcnt` (shifted one in new df) as join keys.

```
# OBTAIN GROUP COUNT (FOR MERGE IDs)
data1$idcnt <- sapply(1:nrow(data1), function(i) sum(data1[1:i, c("id")] == data1$id[i]))
data1$nextidcnt <- data1$idcnt + 1

# MERGE
dfm <- merge(data1, data1, by.x=c("id", "nextidcnt"), by.y=c("id", "idcnt"))

# CALCULATE NEW COLUMNS
dfm <- transform(dfm,
                 start = ifelse(is.na(stop.x), start.x, stop.x + 1),
                 no_days = no_days.x,
                 stop = start.y - 1,
                 drug = 0,
                 dead = dead.x)  

# ROW BIND ORIGINAL SUBSET WITH NEW ROWS
finaldf <- rbind(data1[data1$start != 0, c(1:6)],
                 dfm[dfm$start < dfm$stop,
                     c("id", "start", "no_days", "stop", "drug", "dead")])

finaldf <- finaldf[with(finaldf, order(id, start, stop)),]  # ORDER BY ID, START, STOP
rownames(finaldf) <- NULL                                   # RESET ROW NAMES
```

**Output**

```
finaldf

#    id start no_days stop drug dead
# 1   1     0      NA  182    0    0
# 2   1   183      28  211    1    0
# 3   1   210      28  238    1    0
# 4   1   239      28  240    0    0
# 5   1   241      28  269    1    1
# 6   5     0      NA  182    0    0
# 7   5   183       7  190    1    0
# 8   5   187      28  215    1    0
# 9   5   212      28  240    1    0
# 10  5   241      28  243    0    0
# 11  5   244      28  272    1    1
# 12  7     0      NA  117    0    0
# 13  7   118      28  146    1    0
# 14  7   139      28  167    1    0
# 15  7   168      28  187    0    0
# 16  7   188      28  216    1    0
# 17  7   212      28  240    1    0
# 18  7   237      28  265    1    1
```

Comment: Very clever that worked, thank you. Interested if anyone comes back with a survSplit solution.